# Is it possible to run GridLab-D on macOS Catalina?

Tags: macos-catalina

I have downloaded and installed the latest version of [GridLAB](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gridlab-d/) on my macbook running with macOS 10.15.5 Catalina.

However I am struggling to find and follow a step by step guide to install and use it on my mac.

Can anyone please help me with this.

At the same time, I tried to check the version of Gridlab with

```
gridlabd --version
```

However, it resulted in the following error message in the terminal.

```
% gridlabd --version
dyld: Symbol not found: __ZdlPvm
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/gridlabd
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
 in /usr/local/bin/gridlabd
zsh: abort      gridlabd --version
```

I have used Gridlab earlier on a Windows machine but I am struggling to get it run on a mac.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I got the similar issue on MacOS Big Sur.
I followed [the official building instruction](https://github.com/gridlab-d/gridlab-d/blob/master/README-MACOSX) with some modifications to build gridlabd successfully on mac. The detailed steps:

Install homebrew

```
  % /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL
```

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"

Install git, gcc, autoconf, automake, libtool, gnu-sed

```
  % brew install git gcc autoconf automake libtool gnu-sed
```

Get gridlabd source code with git

```
  % git clone https://github.com/gridlab-d/gridlab-d.git
```

Checkout to v4.1.0

```
  % cd gridlab-d
  % git checkout -b branch-v4.1.0 v4.1.0
```

build and install XercesC and cppunit:

```
  % cd third_party
  % tar -xzf xerces-c-3.2.0.tar.gz
  % cd xerces-c-3.2.0
  % ./configure --disable-static CFLAGS=-O2 CXXFLAGS=-O2
  % make && make install
  # note you need to input you system password before the final step of the following command
  % bash install_cppunit
```

Finally change back to the main code directory, and modify the files of `climate/climate.cpp` and `gldcore/platform.h`:

```
  % cd ..
  % vim climate/climate.cpp
  % vim gldcore/platform.h
  % git diff

diff --git a/climate/climate.cpp b/climate/climate.cpp
index ad2b0a08..2441d710 100644
--- a/climate/climate.cpp
+++ b/climate/climate.cpp
@@ -9,6 +9,7 @@
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <errno.h>
 #include <math.h>
+#include <cmath>
 #include <vector>
 #include <algorithm>
 #include <iostream>
diff --git a/gldcore/platform.h b/gldcore/platform.h
index f60367ea..93793256 100644
--- a/gldcore/platform.h
+++ b/gldcore/platform.h
@@ -45,8 +45,10 @@
        #ifndef isfinite
                #define isfinite finite
        #endif
-       #define min fmin /**< min macro */
-       #define max fmax /**< max macro */
+       //#define min fmin /**< min macro */
+       //#define max fmax /**< max macro */
+       #define max(a,b) ((a) > (b) ? (a) : (b))
+       #define min(a,b) ((a) < (b) ? (a) : (b))
        #ifdef X64
                #define NATIVE int64    /**< native integer size */
        #else
```

configure and build

```
  % autoreconf -isf
  % CFLAGS=-Wno-everything CPPFLAGS=-Wno-everything ./configure
  % make && make install
```

Check gridlabd installation:

```
  % gridlabd --version
  GridLAB-D 4.1.0-18109 (Lugo [46541cb8:branch-v4.1.0:Mod]) 64-bit MACOSX RELEASE
```